# How to save user data in db, without logging in?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am working on a simple app that allows users to search for something using an API and save it to view later.

However, I don't want to integrate authentication in the app. I can, but would rather not as a UX decision. Do you know of a way to generate a device token, that is unique to every device and can be used to store which assets a device has saved in the db?

I am thinking of expo push tokens as a possible solution, but that would require users to accept push notifications - so what happens if a user says no?

Comment: You can try using Firebase anonymous auth but you lose the UID once user logs out. Is that fine with your use case? User can always upgrade to a permanent account by using any auth provider or email.

Comment: i was hoping to persist anonymous authentication. does "log out" apply when you close the app? @Dharmaraj

Comment: I don't think users are logged out when they close app on Android*. For a web app if you've set auth persistence to NONE, then they'll be logged out when browser tab is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could just use react-native-uid to generate a unique id for your device and then store it in AsyncStorage and fetch it from there going forward.

For more inspiration, or perhaps just a more canonical way to do this... read up on suggestions surroundings the recently deprecated constant for installationId here:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants

I haven't used this before but if you're looking for something bullet proof then this is probably your goal of getting the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) might be ideal to use in this case. This can be used to create a user in Firebase auth without any credentials and can be useful especially when you are using either of Firebase's databases since you can use security rules with user's UIDs.

However, once the user logs out of the account by any means including but not limited to using sign out option in your app, clearing app data or uninstalling the app, *the same account with that UID **cannot** be recovered*. I looked up for AsyncStorage and apparently that gets cleared to if the app is deleted.