# Prevent Firestore spam without requiring login

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm making a meal-ordering app demo for fun with React Native and Firebase. I don't want users to have to register in order to make an order, since this can be a point of friction. But at the same time, if I allow writes without authentication, this is a major security hole. How can I solve this? I was thinking of something like registering an account without user interaction, just to keep track of valid clients.

Comment: Are you looking for [Anonymous Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)? Checkout [How to save user data in db, without logging in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68988993)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj can anonymous login state be persisted across app reload?

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned in the answer. If a user logs out in any way like clearing data or explicit login, there is no way to recover the same. You can always upgrade that to a permanent when user decides to check out

Comment: @Dharmaraj this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. If you submit this as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firebase Anonymous Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) can be useful here. Users don't have to enter any credentials to create an account and you can then also use security rules. However, do note that there is no way to recover an account if users logs out in any way.

Also checkout:

1. [Firebase Auth Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)
2. [How to save user data in db, without logging in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68988993/how-to-save-user-data-in-db-without-logging-in)